# Error when saving high score for a game?

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

So, I'm making a game and I thought it would be a cool feature to save the high score of the user (only one person) so it could be compared with the score the player got at the end of the game they just played.  I figured the easiest way to do this would be to write the high score onto a text document (I actually made it a .dat so that it was harder for users to edit) and then retrieve it when I needed it.  So, me being a big fan of OOP, I made a class called "HighScoreSave," which would manage this, then I could just use the object to call save() and load().  Unfortunately, before I started, I knew nothing about BufferedWriters, Readers, PrintWriters, or any other type of Java file editor.  So, without further to do, here is what I put down.  I know, it's probably littered with unconventional practices, but that's why I'm here, right? :P

```
public class HighscoreSave {

String filename;
File file;
BufferedReader in;
FileWriter writer;
PrintWriter out;
Game game;
int currentScore = 0;
String currentScoreString = "";``
String highScore = "";

public HighscoreSave(Game game) {
    filename = "data/highscore.dat";
    file = new File(filename);
    this.game = game;
}

public void save() throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    currentScore = game.getScore();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("");
    sb.append(currentScore);
    currentScoreString = sb.toString();
    highScore = in.readLine();
    int tempHighScore = Integer.parseInt(highScore.trim());

    if(tempHighScore < currentScore){
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
        out = new PrintWriter(writer);
        out.write(highScore);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}

public int load() throws IOException {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    highScore = in.readLine();
    int highScoreInt = Integer.parseInt(highScore);
    in.close();
    return highScoreInt;
}
```

}

Basically, what I'm trying to do is use a method (save()) to check if the current score is better, and if so make a new file that has the new high score on it, and ultimately deleting the old one.  Then, I use load() to return the high score so it can be used in my game class when the game is over.  But it refuses to change the file, and now it just writes zero, zero, zero over and over, resulting in a high score of zero...

Am I missing something?  How do I work out this error, or is there a way better way to do this?

Comment: "I actually made it a .dat so that it was harder for users to edit" ...how does changing the file name make it any harder to edit? Also, what's the point of `sb.append("");`?

Comment: Close the input file immediately after reading in data, and certainly before trying to overwrite it. You're doing funky things in that code, creating files and ignoring them. I strongly urge you to go through a file input and output tutorial without delay. Don't guess at this chit.

Comment: I don't know, that's just what I read. :/  As far as the point of sb.append(""), I wasn't sure either.  Again, something I read on the internet.  Originally I had it commented out, because it seemed stupid to me, but it started telling me my code was in "incorrect format" when I tried to add it to my question...

Comment: Okay.  Is there a way for me to overwrite what the file says, instead of making new files?

Comment: Create a new File of the same name as the one you want to replace, and save it. Simple as that. I think that you may be making things too difficult for yourself.

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) is what you need.

Comment: This belongs of code review.